# Get the first part of a url path

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, path

If I have a url like:

http://localhost:53830/Organisations/1216/View

I want to alert the first part of the url path in lowercase format e.g. 'organisations'

So far I have:

```
var first = $(location).attr('pathname');

first.indexOf(1);

first.replace('/', '');

first.toLowerCase();

alert(first);
```

but it's not working as intended. Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var first = $(location).attr('pathname');

first.indexOf(1);

first.toLowerCase();

first = first.split("/")[1];

alert(first);
```

Answer (score 111):

This will never throw an error because pathname always starts with a `/`, so the minimum length of the resulting array will be two after splitting:

```
const firstPath = location.pathname.split('/')[1];
```

If we are at the domain root, the returned value will be an empty string `''`

---

```
const path = location.pathname.split('/');

path = [
  '', 
  'questions', 
  '8082239', 
  'get-the-first-part-of-a-url-path', 
  '8082346'
];
```

Comment: Although this answer was 6 minutes late 9 years ago, this should be the accepted answer. This does it without JQuery and in a single line.

Comment: If you have a different url name that deals with more '.' than '/',  try using window.location.host.split('.')[0]  .    Or log window.location and use the best options available to you.  Thanks for the help Samuel!

Comment: What's the reason the [0]-th pathname returns an empty string and that the real first path is [1]?

Answer (score 4):

try to use `first.split('/')` so you will end up with an array of strings like

```
['http:' ,'',  'localhost:53830' ,  'Organisations' ,  '1216' ,  'View' ]
```

then find the one the is right after localhost:53830

Answer (score 4):

You can use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

```
const first = new URL(location.href).pathname.split("/")[1]
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using an URL object instead of just `location.pathname` here?

Answer (score 3):

You may need to add `window` keyword so you don't get `error:Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined`

```
var location = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

**JS**

```
const firstPath = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
```

**jQuery**

```
var first = $(location).attr('pathname');  first.indexOf(1);  first.toLowerCase();  first = first.split("/")[1];  alert(first);
```